# Problema al mostrar datos de una DB en tabla HTML

Tags: java, html, mysql, base-de-datos, jsp

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde debo mostrar datos ya registrados en una DB en una tabla HTML. Sin embargo, arroja el siguiente error:

> java.sql.SQLException: After end of result set

Y este es el código:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="ejb.Asignatura_1FacadeLocal"%>
<%@page import="ejb.Asignatura_1Facade"%>
<%@page import="modelo.Asignatura_1"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <%
        Connection con;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/colegio1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "");
        PreparedStatement ps;
        ResultSet rs;
        
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM asignatura");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
    %>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Asignaturas</h1>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Horas</th>
            </tr>
            <%
                while(rs.next());
            %>
            <tr>
                <th><%= rs.getInt("codigo_asignatura")%></th>
                <th><%= rs.getString("nombre_asignatura")%></th>
                <th><%= rs.getString("cantHoras")%></th>>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

He encontrado soluciones con PHP, pero no uso ese lenguaje.

Espero que se entienda mi problema. Agradezco de antemano vuestra disposición.

Comment: Tienes un error aquí: `while(rs.next());`, realmente `while` es un bucle, que en este caso se abriría para leer cada fila y llenar la tabla. Prueba a ponerlo así: `<% while(rs.next()) { %> <tr> <th><%= rs.getInt("codigo_asignatura")%></th> <th><%= rs.getString("nombre_asignatura")%></th> <th><%= rs.getString("cantHoras")%></th>> </tr> <% } %>`

Comment: Si observas bien, hay un bloque donde se abre el bucle: `<% while(rs.next()) { %>` usando `{` y al final se cierra ese bloque con: `<% } %>` Otra cosa que parece extraña es que uses `th`, los cuales suelen usarse solamente para los encabezados de tablas, para las celdas con datos se suele usar `<td> </td>`

Comment: Muchas gracias! problema resuelto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error aquí: `while(rs.next());`, realmente `while` es un bucle, que en este caso se abriría para leer cada fila y llenar la tabla.

Prueba a ponerlo así:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Codigo</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Horas</th>
        </tr>
        <%
            while(rs.next()) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <th><%= rs.getInt("codigo_asignatura")%></th>
            <th><%= rs.getString("nombre_asignatura")%></th>
            <th><%= rs.getString("cantHoras")%></th>>
        </tr>
        <%
            }
        %>
    </table>
```

Si observas bien, hay un bloque donde se abre el bucle: `<% while(rs.next()) { %>` usando `{` y al final se cierra ese bloque con: `<% } %>`.

Otra cosa que parece extraña es que uses `th`, los cuales suelen usarse solamente para los encabezados de tablas, para las celdas con datos se suele usar `<td> </td>`.

También, por lo general, antes de leer resultados con `rs.next()` convendría verificar que realmente hay datos.